# Passing image source to aspx code behind

Tags: asp.net, image, upload, aviary

I'm trying to use Adobe's new Aviary/Feather SDK with an existing aspx webpage.

Here is the HTML for the Feather integration.
you will notice that i had to add `https://test.mywebsite.com` before the `<% imgEvent.imageUrl %>` . Without the website url appended to the beginning the Feather would not work properly.

**ASPX page**

```
<div class="span12">
  <div id='injection_site'></div>
  <asp:Image ID="imgEvent" runat="server" />
  <p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('imgEvent', 'https://test.mywebsite.com<%= imgEvent.ImageUrl.ToString()%>');" /></p>
</div>
```

This will result in the following 
**HTML page**

```
<div class="span12">
  <div id='injection_site'></div>
   <img id="imgEvent" src="/image/get/webfile/80a556a0-c251-4fc5-b6e2-9061d8f90f18" />
   <p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('imgEvent', 'https://test.mywebsite.com/image/get/webfile/80a556a0-c251-4fc5-b6e2-9061d8f90f18');" /></p>
</div>
```

The **problem** seems to be that once Feather is used and the image has been affected with the desired effects, the Html is updated like so

```
<img id="imgEvent" src="http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2014-10-27/1d6ab55fcc2ecaf5/f304c34d77bc446aa5fb6278dcbea5da.png">
```

This is because i assume the file is temporarily being stored on their website for the preview. How would i go about downloading this file using the ASPX code behind method?

If i do `Me.imgEvent.ImageUrl` it will give me the url that was associated to the img on page_load. (`Me.imgEvent.imageUrl = "/image/get/webfile/80a556a0-c251-4fc5-b6e2-9061d8f90f18"`)

Is there a way to pass the new img `src` parameter to the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call to your server with the new url as a parameter. For instance, using the jQuery library, and assuming you have an aspx page with a POST handler, you could do the following:

```
function onSave(id, url) {
  $.post( "saveImage.aspx", { newUrl: url });
}
```